# Blue Status Bar in Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm trying to create a menu for a mobile game in Unity. It's pretty simple, I have a MainCanvas attached to a camera and inside this canvas is an image containing a sprint (for the background) but when I launch the App on a android device I will always get this little blue status bar at the top when using Landscape mode. How can I remove that?

[image: Unity]

Comment: Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Resolution and Presentation -> Status Bar Hidden.

Comment: It actually is hidden :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was fixed by deleting the MainCanvas and setting it up freshly